# Java List element is undefined inside anchor tag

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

There is a list defined as:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Abc", "Def");
```

The problem is inside anchor tag the list element is coming as undefined.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
  <a id="<%=list.get(i)%>" href="javascript:;" onClick="openWindow(<%=list.get(i)%>);" align="left">Proceed</a>
 }
```

The openWindow function is defined as below:

```
function OpenHierarchyWindow(id) {
  alert("id value "+id.value);
}
```

The alert function is giving output as undefined. Why the `list.get(i)` is unable to fetch the data inside the anchor tag.

Comment: Unrelated, but the inline `onClick` won’t work as written since the string isn’t quoted.

Comment: @DaveNewton onClick is working and I am getting the alert. The problem is list.get(i) is not fetching the list elements.

Comment: What HTML is generated when you render the JSP?

Comment: Inside the OpenHierarchyWindow() another window is opening```window.open("list.htm?ACTION=loadData&DIMENSIONS="+id.value,"WindowDimension1","width=600,height=570,top=100,left=200,scrollbars=1");```.  This window is opened but ```DIMENSIONS="+id.value``` is generated as Dimensions=undefined because of above said issue (list.get(i) is coming as undefined inside anchor tag)

Comment: `<%@ attribute name="list" type="java.util.Collection" %>`? post complete code or at least reproducible code.

Comment: It’s a lost of strings, there’s no `id.value`. If this snippet is not what the code actually is there’s no way to help.

Answer (score 0):

here JSP scriplets inside onClick javascript function should be quoted.
You can replace

```
onClick="openWindow(<%=list.get(i)%>);"
```

With

```
onClick="openWindow('<%=list.get(i)%>');"
```

Below is complete code for the same.

```
<%@ page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.Arrays"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>JSP Scriplets And Java Script</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenHierarchyWindow(id) {
        alert("id value " + id);
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>

    <%
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Abc", "Def");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {%>
    <a id="<%=list.get(i)%>" href="javascript:;" onClick="OpenHierarchyWindow('<%=list.get(i)%>');" align="left">Proceed</a>
    <%}%>
</body>
</html>
```